# Returning a file in a HTTP response

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httpresponse

I'm very new to Node JS and would appreciate any help/advice.

Using NodeJS, I have created a local server run [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment#Testing_your_Nodejs_and_NPM_installation) (it's simply a hello world)

From there, I have used [this stack overflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40202327/9822083) , which responds by the request type made.

I'd like to take this a step further, and when the reponse.method is get/post/etc. - I'd like the response to be a file.

In other words, I'd like to return a file from a HTTP response.

In theory, something along the lines of:

```
if(request.method == "GET")
{
    response.end("C:\[file path]\test.txt");
}
```

I've tried simply copying/pasting the file directory after response.end('file directory') but was not opening the file that I wanted it to.

```
const http = require("http");
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 8091;

var server = http.createServer ( function(request,response){

response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text\plain"});
if(request.method == "GET")
    {
        response.end("received GET request.")
    }
else if(request.method == "POST")
    {
        response.end("received POST request.");
    }
else
    {
        response.end("Undefined request .");
    }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send file data by first reading the file using the `fs` module's `readFile` method, and then sending it via `res.write()` followed by `res.end()`, or just `res.end()` as you have done. Here's an example:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data) {
            if (err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end(data);
            return;
        });
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

I answered a similar question to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56285824/4882724